# Let $c(X) = (X \times I ) /(X \times \{0\})$. Show that $c(S^{n-1}) \approx \overline{B}^n$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $c(X) = (X \times I ) /(X \times \{0\})$. Show that $c(S^{n-1}) \approx \overline{B}^n$.

So I need to show that the cone of the sphere $n-1$ is homeomorphic to the $n$ ball. I'm a bit confused about the construction of $c(X)$, what does the "$/$" symbol mean? It's not set difference right?

Anyway I thought about the map $f : c(S^{n-1}) \to \overline{B}^n, f(x) = \frac{tx}{\|x\|}$, but this clearly doesn't work itself. It seems that I would somehow need to get this up by one dimension to map the cone to the ball?

Comment: The $/$ here is probably quotient space

Comment: See the *adjuntion space* example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Examples). I suggest you to read the whole article.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea was correct. Define
$$\phi : S^{n-1} \times I \to \bar B^n, \phi(x,t) = tx.$$
We have $\phi(S^{n-1} \times \{0\}) =\{0\}$, thus $\phi$ induces
$$f : c(S^{n-1}) \to \bar B^n$$
on the quotient. It is easy to check that $f$ is a continuous bijection and therefore a homeomorphism since $c(S^{n-1})$ is compact and $\bar B^n$ Hausdorff.